# To count the article in the sentence?In this program last if statement not working "a" and "an"

Tags: c++

```
//header  
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
    
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string s,s1=" ";
    int i,j,flag=0,flag1=0,count=0;
    getline(cin,s);
    for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s[i]==' '){
            flag=i;
            for(j=flag1;j<flag;j++){
               s1=s1+s[j];
               flag1=flag+1;
            }
            //cout<<s1<<" ";--uncommenting this works but below if statement not working
            if(s1=="a"||s1=="A"||s1=="an"||s1=="An"){
                count++;
            }
        }
        s1=" ";
    }
    cout<<count;
}
```

If statement taking nothing and just giving count value as 0

Comment: Some recommended reading: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: can you add the input sample

Comment: it is showing 0 in every output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `s1` is initialized to a whitespace character and it is preventing it from matching with the strings in the `if` statement, none of which don't have whitespace characters.

Remove the extra two whitespaces and initialize `s1` to empty strings.

Comment: [Here is a demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A8Luzo6G3ke2RpMA). What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Thanks MikeCAT, I done a silly mistake given extra space for s1 ,now it worked

Answer (score 0):

In a better way and to make the life easier, you could do the same stuff with the help of `std::stringstream` and `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::string string;
    std::string temp;
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    int counter = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, string);

    // a string stream to separate each word
    std::stringstream ss(string);

    // pushing the separated words (by space) into a dynamic array
    while (ss >> temp)
        words.push_back(temp);

    // comparing each array of 'words' (where each separated words are stored
    // as a type of 'std::string'
    for (size_t i = 0, len = words.size(); i < len; i++)
        if (words.at(i) == "a" || words.at(i) == "an" || \
                words.at(i) == "A" || words.at(i) == "An")
            counter++;

    // if no articles found, i.e. the counter is zero
    if (counter == 0) {
        std::cout << "Sorry, there were no articles found.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    // otherwise...
    std::cout << counter << " number of articles were found!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

A sample output is as follows:

```
Enter a string: A great scientist, Newton experimented something on an apple.
//             _^___________________________________________________^^_______
2 number of articles were found!
```

Also, avoid the usage of `bits/stdc++.h`, it's neither the part of Standard C++ nor a good convention to use as directed in [@ChrisMM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054808/to-count-the-article-in-the-sentencein-this-program-last-if-statement-not-worki/63055819#comment111503746_63054808)'s comment in this post.

Using `using namespace std` for smaller programs where the chance of naming ambiguity is negligible, is good, but better avoid in large programs.

Comment: Thankyou for your advice and giving time for answering me, I will do it as you said but I am still wondering why my if statement not working.